# Spring Using SpEL Principal

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm trying to use SpEL has in this document 
https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions to do a query filtering results by the ?#{principal.id}

The problem is that Spring returns an exception

> org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set:
>   [1] [select p , p.store, p.category from Product p JOIN p.store s 
>   JOIN p.category c  WHERE p.store.id = :id AND p.keywords LIKE :keyword
>   AND p.store.ownerId = ?1 ]; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: Not
>   all named parameters have been set: [1] [select p , p.store,
>   p.category from Product p JOIN p.store s  JOIN p.category c  WHERE
>   p.store.id = :id AND p.keywords LIKE :keyword AND p.store.ownerId = ?1
>   ]

I have setup the following code and it is being executed.

```
@Service
public class SecurityEvaluationContextExtension extends EvaluationContextExtensionSupport {

    @Override
    public String getExtensionId() {
        return "security";
    }

    @Override
    public SecurityExpressionRoot getRootObject() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        System.out.println("SER >>>>> " + authentication.getPrincipal().toString() + " -- " );
        return new SecurityExpressionRoot(authentication) {};
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    EvaluationContextExtension securityExtension() {
        return new SecurityEvaluationContextExtension();
    }

}
```

I'm using this server has a Spring Resource Server and so using the translation bellow to get the Id from the Authorization server. I confirm the code is executing and translating well but I'm getting the exception above.

```
@Service
public class myPrincipalExtractor implements PrincipalExtractor {

    @Override
    public UserInfo extractPrincipal(Map<String, Object> map) {

        Map<String,Object> principal = null;

        if (map.containsKey("principal")) {
            principal = (Map<String, Object>) map.get("principal");
        }

        UserInfo user = new UserInfo();

        if (principal != null ) {
            if (principal.containsKey("id")) {
                user.setId(Long.parseLong(principal.get("id").toString()));
            }

            if (principal.containsKey("username")) {
                user.setUsername(principal.get("username").toString());
            }

            if (principal.containsKey("email")) {
                user.setEmail(principal.get("email").toString());
            }
        }

        System.out.println("----> " + user.getUsername() + " -> " + user.getId());

        return user;
    }
}
```

The query is...

```
@CrossOrigin
public interface StoreRepository extends CrudRepository<Store, Long>
{
    @Query("select p , p.store, p.category from Product p JOIN p.store s " +
            " JOIN p.category c " +
            " WHERE p.store.id = :id AND p.keywords LIKE %:keyword% AND p.store.ownerId = ?#{principal.id} ")
    List<Product> findByKeywordIgnoreCase(@Param("id") Long id , @Param("keyword") String keyword);
}
```

More Information:

I did this code bellow in the SecurityExpressionRoot so now I know this is really getting called when I place the SpEL and the ID and Username exist in the object. Also tried casting the returned object to Principal and the same problem happened.

> AND p.store.ownerId = ?#{principal.id}

```
return new SecurityExpressionRoot(authentication) {
            @Override
            public UserInfo getPrincipal() {
                System.out.println("Fetching the principal has user " + authentication.getPrincipal().toString());
                return (UserInfo) authentication.getPrincipal();
            }
        };
```

Comment: I'm using a similar spel for a sample project, you can see it at github but in my case I'm not using `PincipalExtractor`, in this example I'm using a `UserDetailService` in order to retrieve the principal with a custom id field: https://github.com/faustocdiaz/spring-security-spel-sample

Comment: I'm using a OAuth2 ResourceServer that get's it's information from a Authorization Server. Given your solution I would need to build a restTemplate client?

Comment: Hi Fernando, I think this example combine both methods, the oauth2 and the UserDetailService in order to fill `principal` objects fields with the values that you need to inject into the `@Query` annotation, https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/  see the `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter` and `WebSecurityConfiguration` sections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the website example (https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions) they specify you can use ?#{principal.id} and that really gets called when executing the code above but it fails on the @Query binding for some reason.
However I tried running it with another example case

```
@Query("select p , p.store, p.category from Product p JOIN p.store s " +
            " JOIN p.category c " +
            " WHERE p.store.id = :id AND p.keywords LIKE %:keyword% AND p.store.ownerId = ?#{#security.principal.id} ")
```

And this worked.
I found this other example here:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/master/jpa/security/src/main/java/example/springdata/jpa/security/SecureBusinessObjectRepository.java

Comment: Might have been related to this bug, https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1140 but I was able to use the SpEL with #securiy.principal instead of just #principal