# Search records for logged in user using spring-jpa

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am newbie to spring-boot and trying to create a web application for tracking expenses. I have used spring security to implement login mechanism. Below are the entities for expenses and user.

User entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name="user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "email")
    @Email(message = "*Please provide a valid Email")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide an email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "password")
    @Length(min = 5, message = "*Your password must have at least 5 characters")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "name")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your last name")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "active")
    private int active;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;

}
```

Expense entity:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name="expense")
@Data
public class Expense {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private Instant expenseDate;

    private Double amount;

    private String description;

    private String paymentType;

    @ManyToOne
    private Category category;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
}
```

Expense entity has User reference.

ExpenseRepository:

```
@Repository("expenseRepository")
public interface ExpenseRepository extends JpaRepository<Expense,Long> {

    @Query(value="SELECT sum(e.amount) from Expense e")
    public Double totalExpenses();

    @Query(value="select c.name as category, sum(e.amount) as amount from Category c, Expense e where c.id=e.category.id group by c.name")
    public List<ExpenseByCategory> getExpensesPerCategory();

    @Query(value="select e.paymentType as paymentType, sum(e.amount) as amount from Expense e group by e.paymentType")
    public List<ExpenseByPaymentType> getExpensesByPaymentType();

}
```

I want to return expense records only for the current logged in user based on its id. I am not able to construct the @Query to do this and extract current logged in user details.

Please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Using SpEL Principal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45901014/spring-using-spel-principal)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
import java.security.Principal;

public ReturnType methodName(Principal principal){
      System.out.println(principal);
      System.out.println(principal.getName());
}
```

You can use this also

```
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;

Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
System.out.println(authentication.getName());
```